# DownloadManger sends ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE broadcast on no Wi-Fi

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I have an android OS project and I am using the DownloadManger to perform some updates. Everything works fine with the download but I have an issue with the switching between Wi-Fi and mobile network.

The case is:
I am connected to Wi-Fi and start the download, 10 second later I cut the Wi-Fi so the phone switches instantly to mobile network. The problem is that the download stops and I have to restart it from the beginning.

From the logs I can see that the DownloadManger terminates everything but I can see why:

```
2022-12-06 11:07:07.847 2519-3467 DownloadManager com.android.providers.downloads W [18] Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR: Failed reading response: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort
2022-12-06 11:07:07.851 2519-3467 DownloadManager com.android.providers.downloads D [18] Finished with status CANNOT_RESUME
2022-12-06 11:07:07.947 2519-2519 DownloadManager com.android.providers.downloads D onStopJob id=18, reason=cancel() called by app, callingUid=10049 uid=10049 jobId=18
```

Also, the reason the download cannot restart is that I receive a broadcast from the DownloadManager which states that the download finished but the status is failure so the code removes the temp file.

The broadcast I receive is DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE and I can't find any reason or documentation on why I receive this even the download failed.

I think the request should stay in PENDING or AWAITING_CONNECTION but non of this happens.

The config of the request:

```
 Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(updateInfo.getDownloadUrl()));
    String userAgent = Utils.getUserAgentString(context);
    if (userAgent != null) {
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
    }
    request.addRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    request.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));
    request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse(fullFilePath));
    request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
    request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);

 // Start the download
        final DownloadManager dm =
                (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        Utils.cancelNotification(context);

        long downloadId = dm.enqueue(request);
        updateInfo.setDownloadId(downloadId);
```

Any suggestion will be quite helpful, thanks!

Comment: `think the request should stay in PENDING or AWAITING_CONNECTION but non of this happens.` Nice example of whishfull thinking ;-)

Comment: "The broadcast I receive is DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE and I can't find any reason or documentation on why I receive this even the download failed" -- "complete" does not imply success. It indicates that `DownloadManager` is no longer going to work with on this particular download. You can query to find out status details regarding the download.

Comment: You are right. The status is failure so I assume the service lost complete connection to the internet for some reason.